# Login doesn't work with Django + nginx + uwsgi

Tags: django, authentication, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I have quite simple login logic - similar to official Django solution.

```
class Login(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = AuthenticationForm

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return self._get_success_url(self.request)
        return super(Login, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.auth(self.request, form.get_user())
        return super(Login, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, u'Invalid username or password')
        return super(Login, self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self._get_success_url(self.request)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_success_url(request):
        if 'next' in request.GET:
            return request.GET['next']
        return settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

    @staticmethod
    def auth(request, user):
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                assert user == request.user

                if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                    request.session.delete_test_cookie()

                messages.success(request, u'Success.')
            else:
                messages.error(request, u'Deactivated account.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, u'Invalid password or username.')

        request.session.set_test_cookie()
```

On development server everything works fine. But on production server login fails. User is logged and the message `Success.` is shown, but user instance disappears from `request.user`.

What is even more strange - if I restart services (nginx + uwsgi), for the first time login works. If I log out and try again, it doesn't work.

Second strange thing - login to Django administration works always fine.

I am running on:

```
Ubuntu == 12.04 LTS
nginx == 1.1.19
uwsgi == 1.0.3-debian
MariaDB == 5.5.34
Django == 1.5
```

Comment: please upgrade uWSGI as soon as possibile, you are using a version of 3 years ago with ended support and lot of known bugs. Maybe it is not related to your specific problem, but at least it would be easier to debug it

Comment: Wow, bingo. I upgraded from 1.0.3 to 2.0 and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Troubles were caused by older version of uwsgi. After upgrading from 1.0.3 to 2.0 log in works all right.